# How ot achive table cells combined of fixed width and shrinked to content?

Tags: html, css

assume i have a table, some of the cells should have a with equal to their content, some a fixed with and the others could fill the rest.
i used the 100% method then i lost the fixed size. Every thing i do, i can not achieve both:

```
.theTable{
    display:table; 
    width:80%; /* or whatever width for table*/
    height: 200px;
}

.theCell{
    display:table-cell;
    padding:0px 2px;
    white-space: pre; /* this will avoid line breaks*/    
    border:1px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.bigCell{
    width:100%; /* this will shrink other cells */
}
.fixedCell {
    height: 40px;
    width: 70px;

}
```

any helps?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/80nmuxs8/4/

Comment: Why not just use `<table>` instead of `<div>`? Your HTML doesnt look semantic.

Comment: @user2520818 remove the width: 100%; from .bigCell. What is 100% of 100%?

Comment: @RahulDesai, changed with table and td. the problem is still the styling not the markup semantic.

Comment: @Gezzasa, if i remove the 100% then the last cell's width won't shrink to its content. which is my problem that i can only achieve one. the fixed one or the shrinked to centent one.

Comment: @user2520818 try http://jsfiddle.net/80nmuxs8/5/. I have put the cell to fit contents width to 1%. works. I will add answer if you approve

Comment: @Gezzasa, your fiddle looks like what i want. can you explain why the 1% works?

Comment: @user2520818 To be honest I am not sure. Divs will take be as big as the content inside (unless you have a static width) so with 1% (or even 0%) it will be the smallest while displaying all content in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix

http://jsfiddle.net/80nmuxs8/5/

If you set the width of the cell that you want filled according to the contents to 1%, it will grow according to the content.

the .bigCell doesn't need a width as it will take up the remaining space.

```
 .contentCell {width: 1%}
```

Comment: How about in IE8? it gets the width of 1% of the row. is there a fall back for?

Comment: I have tested this in IE8 now (I only have IE 11 so have to put browser mode on IE8). It works for me. The cell still only takes up the size of the content.

Comment: thanx for your replay. hmmm, i also use the browser mode. and the cell shrinks to really 1%. i tried to simplify my markup and style, removed all paddings, margins, border, background .. but the width doesn't change. no success with 1px or 0.